# Find the two column combination which has max value in third column in spark sql. Using this column combination find Historical Min and Max

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a hive table with below table. I have to find the right combination of Instance and name with has max value for the latest cyclecode. Hive table also multiple Instance. For each instance i have find correct Instance, name which has Max value for latest cyclecode

```
 Instance   name     value    cyclecode
 A37        ratio.1  10       1
 A37        ratio.2  20       1
 A37        ratio.3  90       1
 A37        ratio.1  10       2
 A37        ratio.2  20       2
 A37        ratio.3  30       2
 A37        ratio.1  10       3
 A37        ratio.2  12       3
 A37        ratio.3  80       3
```

Expected output:

```
Instance   name     value    cyclecode
 A37        ratio.3  80       3
```

With this combination, i have to find Historical Max and Min with previous cyclecode data

Expected output:

```
Instance   name     Historical_min     Historical_max
 A37        ratio.3  30                   90
```

I tried below Spark-sql. But I am not getting expected output:

```
spark.sql("WITH pick_val_max (select MAX(value) as val_max from table WHERE cycle_code = 3 limit 1) SELECT instance, name, value from table, pick_val_max WHERE name RLIKE 'Histogram.ratio' AND cycle_code = 3 and value = pick_val_max.val_max").show(truncate=false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F

df_origin = spark.createDataFrame(
[
{ "Instance":"A37", "name" : "ratio.1","value": 10, "cyclecode" : 1},
{ "Instance":"A37", "name" : "ratio.2","value": 20, "cyclecode" : 1},
{ "Instance":"A37", "name" : "ratio.3","value": 90, "cyclecode" : 1},
{ "Instance":"A37", "name" : "ratio.1","value": 10, "cyclecode" : 2},
{ "Instance":"A37", "name" : "ratio.2","value": 20, "cyclecode" : 2},
{ "Instance":"A37", "name" : "ratio.3","value": 30, "cyclecode" : 2},
{ "Instance":"A37", "name" : "ratio.1","value": 10, "cyclecode" : 3},
{ "Instance":"A37", "name" : "ratio.2","value": 12, "cyclecode" : 3},
{ "Instance":"A37", "name" : "ratio.3","value": 80, "cyclecode" : 3}
])

w = Window().orderBy(F.col('cyclecode').desc(), F.col('value').desc())
df = df_origin.withColumn('rn', F.row_number().over(w))

df = df.filter('rn = 1').drop('rn')
df = df_origin.join(df, ['Instance', 'name'], 'leftsemi')

res_df = df.groupBy('Instance', 'name').agg(F.max('value').alias('Historical_max'), F.min('value').alias('Historical_min'))
```

Output:

```
+--------+-------+--------------+--------------+
|Instance|   name|Historical_max|Historical_min|
+--------+-------+--------------+--------------+
|     A37|ratio.3|            90|            30|
+--------+-------+--------------+--------------+
```